# Lightweight edition of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am a C# developer, I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on a Remote Desktop Connection but it is very laggy and annoying to develop remotely.

So, I wanted to ask what is the lightest edition of Visual Studio (600MB+) which I can get?

I have a high speed internet but the problem is that it is not unlimited (100GB quota only is what I have).

P.S. It is not important for the edition to be 2017, but I want it to be 2012 or higher.

**EDIT**: My problem is not in the disk space which I have, but in my internet quota.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, having to use remote desktop ought to eat a good deal into the 100GB budget.  VS2017 is the lightest, depending on what workloads you choose.  Minimum *install* size is 600MB, max is 83GB.  Download size is less, don't install everything.  But consider to think outside of the box.  A case of beer if pretty light weight.  Make it light beer to be sure.  Take it along when you visit a friend with a good connection.

Comment: @HansPassant - Which edition of VS2017 is the lightest? I know that the only free one is Community but I can buy any other if there's.
Also I think that the free one should be the lightest :/ I am confiused now xD

Comment: Community is free, consider to spend your money on a good connection first.

Comment: @HansPassant - All of our internet plans in my country are limited, the unlimited ones with high speed cost $1,500 (for big companies only).

Comment: Hmm, the interwebs say you can get 300GB in Egypt.  Nobody here can do the shopping for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A blog article [here](https://elegantcode.com/2012/11/30/visual-studio-light-edition/) is stating that "Visual Studio Express" is the smallest in size and exactly as what you wanted (600MB+).

VS Express won't provide you as more features as VS Community, Pro or Enterprise - but it is providing the important ones.

It seems that Visual Studio Express 2017 is the final version of "VS Express" - So Microsoft won't continue the development of "VS Express" anymore.

And if you want to have the final lightweight edition of Visual Studio then I'd recommend Visual Studio Express 2012.

You can download the offline installer of VS Express 2012 here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/5/1F519CC5-0B90-4EA3-8159-33BFB97EF4D9/VS2012_WDX_ENU.iso (608 MB).

And it will require 4GB~ of disk space size to be installed.

Comment: You've saved my day! Thank you very much.